# append value to res object

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to append a value to response before sending it

i.e

```
function refreshToken(req, res, next){
        res.newToken = "derp";
        next();
}

router.get ('/user/', refreshToken, function(req,res,next){
     res.send("some data");
     console.log(res)
} );
```

console.log does show newToken is appened to res
but when I run a ajax function I get "some data" but not the newToken

Answer (score 0):

Well. `res` is not going to just send over any properties that it has. You need to decide in which format/field do you want to communicate newToken to the client. Should it be part of the response body? What is the response body format? Currently you just send `some data` as plain text. Should it be appended to plain text, or should it all be JSON? Or should the token be in HTTP header?

For example, if you want to send the token in a custom header field, you would do

```
res.setHeader("MyCustomTokenHeader", "derp");
```

And then it would show up for the client in HTTP headers.

Comment: I was trying to return it in the response body

Comment: Whenever you're ready to write the response body, you could use Express' helper `res.json(res.mydata)` to send the data. If you want to do it the _streams way_, check [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream).